# $H_{1}([0,1]/A)$ can not be countable generated when $A=\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbf{Z},n>0\}\cup\{0\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I think this is another example when good pairs condition is not satisfied. Suppose $A=\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbf{Z},n>0\}\cup\{0\}$, from the exact sequence of homology group I can get that $H_1([0,1],A)$ is countably generated, but I don't know how to prove that $H_{1}([0,1]/A)$ is not countably generated. Can someone give me some ideas on how to prove that? Thanks!

(I tried to think of it as the wedge sum of countable many $S^{1}$, but its homology group can be countably generated...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your space $A$ is homeomorphic to the *Hawaiian earring* (see my answer to [Construct compact space with some homology group not finitely generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3023089)). This is not the wedge sum of countably many copies of $S^1$ In fact, this wedge sum is a non-compact CW-complex.

Now see [Construct compact space with some homology group not finitely generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3023089) which answers your question.